# Add Outlook Search Folder on shared folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to create a new "Search Folder" in an Outlook shared folder using VBA in Excel.
It is failing on the last line, which is the save function.

> "Object could not be found".

```vb
Sub createfolder()

    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oSearch As Outlook.Search
    Dim oInbox  As Outlook.mapifolder
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim oScope As String
    Dim sFilter As String

    Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set oInbox = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Fin Reporting").Folders("July")

    sFolderPath = oInbox.FolderPath
    sScope = "'" & oInbox.FolderPath & "'"
    Set oSearch = oApp.AdvancedSearch(sScope)
    
    oSearch.Save ("TestSearch")

End Sub
```

Comment: Clearly, it's failing on the line before the last one which is what would create `oSearch`). Are you certain you need `Set` on that line? Also, did none of the 700+ existing posts with the same *Error 424 Object required* help?

Comment: No it is not clear it's failing at second to last. And I took out SET, and it said it needs it. It's definitely dying at the last line. @KenWhite

Comment: I did more reading, and I think my mistake is trying to search on the Shared Inbox. Which I think cannot be done. Can anyone verify that? Anyone have an alternative?

Comment: Your Code seems to be Ok. It is working fine for me. Are you sure you're working on the correct Folders?
The only Thing i would Change is the variable declaration, because you're using "sScope" in your code and you used "dim oScope" on top of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not say where your "fin reporting" folder is located

for this example code, i put it in the top folder, so it is on same level as "inbox"

```
top ---
       |
       fin reporting
       |   |
       |   july
       |
       inbox
       |
       sent items
       |
       etc.
```

try these two. see which one works, or does not work.

single-step through the code by pressing F8 key repeatedly

try this one in outlook

```
Sub createfolder_outlook()

    Dim oInbox  As MAPIFolder
    Dim oSearch As Search

    Set oInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Fin Reporting").Folders("July")
    Set oSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch("'" & oInbox.FolderPath & "'")

    oSearch.Save ("TestSearch")

End Sub
```

then do same in excel

```
Sub createfolder_excel()

    Dim oInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oSearch As Outlook.Search

    Set oInbox = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Fin Reporting").Folders("July")
    Set oSearch = Outlook.Application.AdvancedSearch("'" & oInbox.FolderPath & "'")

    oSearch.Save ("TestSearch")

End Sub
```